# EF (C#) with tunneling to MySQL - optimising database calls

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

So I have program to deal with some sort of work in MySQL database. I'm connecting through SSH tunneling with putty (yes, I know launching programs on server itself would be much better but I don't have a choice here).

I have some problems with programs speed. I solved one by adding ".Include(table_name)" but I can't think about a way to do it here.

So purpose of this method is to clean database of unwanted, broken records. Simplified code looks like this:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDatabase_dataEntities())
{
    List<achievements> achiList = new List<achievements>();
    var achievementsQuery = from data in dbContext.achievements
                            orderby data.playerID
                            select data;
    achiList = achievementsQuery.Skip(counter * 5000).Take(5000).ToList();
    foreach (achievements record in achiList)
    {
        var playerExists = from data in dbContext.players_data
                           where data.playerID == record.playerID
                           select data;
        if(!playerExists.Any())
        {
            dbContext.achievements.Remove(record);
        }
    }
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    counter++;
}
```

So this is built this way because I want to load achievements table then check if achievements have their player in player_data. If such player doesn't exist, remove his achievements.

It is all in do while, so I don't overload my memory by loading all data at once.

I know the problem is with checking in database in foreach steps but I can't figure out how to do it without it. Other things I tried generated errors either because EF couldn't translate it into SQL or exceptions were thrown when trying to access non-existing entity. Doing it in foreach bottlenecks whole program probably because of ping to the server.

I will need similar thing more often so I would be really gratefull if anyone could help me with making it so there is no need to call to database in "foreach". I know I could try to load whole players_data table and then check for Any(), but some tables I need it on are too big for that.

Oh, and turning off tracking changes doesn't help at this point because it is not what slows the program.

I would be gratefull for any help, thanks in advance!

EDIT: Mmmm, is there a way to get achievements which doesn't have player_data corresponding to them through one query using associations? Like adding to achievements query something like:

```
where !data.player_data.Exists()
```

Intellisense shows me that there is nothing like Exists or Any to use at this point. Is there any trick similar to this? It would definitely deal with the problem I have with speed there since database call in foreach wouldn't be needed.

Comment: It would help if your would post your data structure and an example of what you are trying to clean.

Comment: Couple questions to understand context. You need to delete achievements that don't have users, right? Any reason you don't want to run a SQL query on your DB server? Any reason you don't want to use LINQ to Entities (more readable code)?

Comment: There is no big reason behind using SQL other than I want to teach myself how to do it well without SQL. About Linq to Entities, no, I could use answer from LINQ to Entities if it will help with the problem.

I'm not sure what from data structure do you need. This is simple database, tables with data are connected mainly by playerID. But it is also a bit old and after many non-professional changes, thats why it have so many errors - they don't stop the game but interfere with many automation thing like statistics, recalculating things etc

Comment: Do you have a foreign key for `player_data` in `achievements` table? You do, right? In the post you are trying to access `data.player_data` which implicates that Entity Framework generated `player_data` lazy property for you in `achievements` entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete achievements that don't have corresponding user records, then you can user a SQL query below:

```
DELETE a
FROM `achievements` a
LEFT JOIN `user` AS u 
ON u.`playerID` = a.`playerID`
WHERE u.`playerID` IS NULL;
```

SQL query will be an order of magnitude faster than Entity Framework.

If you want to do that in the application, you can use the following code that uses LINQ to Entities and LINQ extensions methods. I assume you have a foreign key for `player_data` in `achievements` table so Entity Framework generates `player_data` lazy property for your `achievements` entity:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDatabase_dataEntities())
{
    var proceed = true;
    while (proceed)
    {
        // Get net 1000 entities to delete
        var entitiesToDelete = dbContext.achievements
            .Where(x => x.players_data == null)
            .Take(1000)
            .ToList();

        dbContext.achievements.RemoveRange(entitiesToDelete);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        // Proceed if deleted entities during this iteration
        proceed = entitiesToDelete.Count() > 0;
    }
}
```

If you prefer to use LINQ query syntax instead of extension methods, then your code will look like:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDatabase_dataEntities())
{
    var proceed = true;
    while (proceed)
    {
        // Get net 1000 entities to delete
        var query = from achievement in dbContext.achievements
                    where achievement.players_data == null
                    select achievement;

        var entitiesToDelete = query.ToList();

        dbContext.achievements.RemoveRange(entitiesToDelete);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        // Proceed if deleted entities during this iteration
        proceed = entitiesToDelete.Count() > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. As I said, I could do that if I had to, but I'm asking more about how to fix it in that way - because I will need similar queries in the future to make sure that my code won't crash on "there is no entity for that player" or similar things. But thanks anyway, if I won't get this LINQ faster than I'll be forced to use SQL so it may come in handy.

Comment: @Ethelnalen added another solutions that uses LINQ to Entities

Comment: I need to read more about LINQ to Entities, this worked like a charm with 2 times less coding. But I had one problem, there is no "RemoveRange" so I had to do it in foreach. Do I need certain version of EF for this function? Anyway that fixes what I needed. big thanks!

Comment: @Ethelnalen I think I misspoke there a little. LINQ to Entities just allows you to query `DbContext` with LINQ queries. What you used in your post is LINQ to Entities too. The difference is that you used LINQ query syntax and I used LINQ extension methods. They do the same under the covers. It a matter of personal preference and code readability.

Comment: @Ethelnalen I like extensions methods more (readability, extendability, etc.). If you feel more comfortable working with SQL like LINQ queries, you can easily rewrite it this way. Updated my answer.

Comment: Extensions look better I just was used to the other queries because thats what was used in tutorials I did. Thanks for explaining it.

Comment: `RemoveRange` was added in EF 6 for convenience. It can faster in some cases though. See remarks here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.removerange(v=vs.113).aspx.